# Count Between three tables

Tags: sql, count, multiple-tables

I have three tables

Data
Service
Status

Data table

```
Serno | ServiceId | Status |    Datetime
1         2           4        12/12/2014
2         1           3        08/12/2014
```

Service

```
ServiceId |  Service Name 
  1             Deployment
  2             Designing
```

Status

```
StatusId   |  Status
 1           Done
 2           Pending
 3           20%done
 4           Canceled
```

I want a Sql code for Count (that is the status count with respect to Services)

```
Designing  0  0  0  1
Deployment 0  0  1  0
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT     COUNT(Service.Status) AS Expr1, Service.ServiceName, Status.Status
FROM         Data INNER JOIN
                      Service ON Hcc_Service_Data.Hcc_Service_Category_Id = Service .ServiceId INNER JOIN
                       Status ON  Data.StatusId = Status.Status_Serno
GROUP BY Service.ServiceName, Status.Status
```

Comment: Can you please name the columns in your output - your question is confusing. what is the logic to get `Designing 0  0  0  1`

Comment: Sorry, that is the status count.

Comment: you want to pivot status count ?

Comment: yes..with respect to the Designations.

Comment: do u want to have `0  0  0  1` in one column, or one column for each number?

Comment: I need the Service and Status ... Like If Service has a status 3 then it should show Designation 0  0  1  0 ..its basically a count keeping the Service as the main content and the Status as the countable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select S.ServiceName, 
(CASE WHEN D.Status=1 then '1' ELSE '0' END) as S1,
(CASE WHEN D.Status=2 then '1' ELSE '0' END) as S2,
(CASE WHEN D.Status=3 then '1' ELSE '0' END) as S3,
(CASE WHEN D.Status=4 then '1' ELSE '0' END) as S4
FROM Data D, Service S where
D.serviceId = S.serviceId;
```

Comment: Sir, you have forgotten the Data tables . Services and status are foreign keys to the Data table. Count is performed on the data table

Comment: I read Data Table earlier as "ServiceStatus". Modified for brevity.